# Which warning one should treat as error in pylint

Tags: pylint

Currently my pylint is configured to emit only errors. This, I believe, is too restrictive. But when I enable warnings, the numbers of warning generated are overwhelmingly large. Many of them are just syntax related. I am not sure which warning has the potential of causing a serious bug. Are there any recommended warnings set one should always enable in pylint. For example in C++, I always treat warning about statement `if(a = 1)` (instead of `if(a == 1)`) as error and it has saved me many times from writing illogical code.